# Delete records in phpmyadmin using a csv file

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin, sql-delete

I want to use phpmyadmin and delete all products from table "products" where reference=SKUxxxxxx
SKUxxxxxx are located in a txt file (list) 1 SKUxxxxxx per line called stop_production.txt .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there are too many to delete. Otherwise, choose sort sequence key for product reference and skip through to first SKU ref. and manually delete until key changes above SKU.
If you want batch load due to high volume:-
I would first export the table to CSV. Make a backup then locally (e.g. via edittor) locate each such product line. Write a programme if too many to edit. Can use Command line .BAT file if stuck for any real programming language and the FIND command. For each line to be deleted, keep the ID number (I am assuming this is a MySQL database used by PHP.) and wipe out all other data. Especially put in a value that would make it appear elsewhere, such as a non-existant menu item. Perhaps there are other records such as order still pointing to it. But even without it at least gets them out of site for the time being. Import the file. (Check it first visually and via edittor). Then...

This doesn't reclaim the space, but it's a step. However, if the file is not being used from the time of the export until the import so that you know the data is unchanged, you can delete the live data (operation TRUNCATE), edit or programmatically delete the SKU product records and import it all back up again. This is better if possible to take data offline.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use interface technology ie (PHP,NODE etc) that reads that file and generate queries from your file 
finally use that query to delete records from Mysql db